# CGImageRelease Error in architecture i386

Tags: ios, avasset

When I build this code I am getting an error,

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:ur];
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(2, 1);
CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

cell.imageView.image=thumbnail;
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

**Error**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_CGImageRelease", referenced from:      
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have added `libc++.dylib` but still error persists. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `CoreGraphics` framework resolves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `QuartzCore.framework` to your project so that the code links. This API is part of QuartzCore framework in iOS. Also, where using it, use `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think it is OS-X framework. And it is not available in IOS when I am trying to add.

Comment: Still same error is occuring. No use of adding `quartzcore.framework`

Comment: @Boggarapu This should resolve your error for sure. Are you creating any static library? If yes, make sure the application that is using your library **also** links to `QuartzCore.framework`.

Comment: I am not using any static library. @Amar

Comment: If possible just give me a **link** for sample code of using  `CGImageRelease` project